# redux form - validate input matches specific length

Tags: validation, redux-form

I'm working with Redux Form and creating validation that will check if the field matches exactly X number of characters. My approach is to determine the length of the input and validate against a specified length.  I am able to successfully console log each character input, but receive an error when trying to log the length of the input.

How can I determine the length of the input within the validator.js file

Error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
//component.js (Redux Form)
import React from 'react';
import {reduxForm, Field, SubmissionError, focus} from 'redux-form';
import Input from './input';
import {exactSix} from '../validators';

export class Contact extends React.Component {
  // onSubmit(values) {}

  render() {
      return (
          <form
            onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(values =>
              this.onSubmit(values)
          )}>
            <Field 
                name="content"
                type="text"
                component={Input}
                label="Match"
                validate={[exactSix]}
            />
            <button
                type="submit"
                disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}>
                Send message
            </button>
          </form>
      );
    }
  }

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'contact',
    onSubmitFail: (errors, dispatch) =>
        dispatch(focus('contact', Object.keys(errors)[0]))
})(Contact);



//validator.js
export const exactSix = value => {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(values.length); //this line is highlighted within the error message
  if(value.length === 6){
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return 'must be exactly six';
  }
}
```

Comment: What is value logging exactly?  What do u mean each character?  Values.length also has an extra “s”

Comment: Value logs whatever has been typed in the input field with each keystroke

Comment: Each letter or the whole word?

Comment: Did u fix the typo and take the s off the values.length?

Comment: Each letter. Yes, the s has been removed from the console.log, but it still displays the error

Comment: Well the length of each letter will only ever equal 1 anyways

Comment: Try taking the brackets off of exactsix ?

Comment: misunderstanding from my end... the value logged in the console displays whatever is currently displayed in the input field. Ex. Typing in "123"; pressing 1 logs "1", pressing 2 logs "12", pressing 3 logs "123", etc. In this case, shouldn't the length of value increase by 1 with each new character added?

Comment: Ok good.  Did you try removing the brackets?

Comment: removing the brackets produced the same results

Comment: And value.length is an error?  Try logging (typeof value )

Comment: value is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `value` is not undefined:

```
export const exactSix = value => {
    return value && value.length !== length
        ? `must be exactly six`
        : undefined;
};
```

> [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp8r3rqo6v)